# Parsing Dates In Python

Tags: python, date, parsing, time

I have a list of dates from input like the ones below.

I am working on a project and only want to accept the dates that follow the format April 1, 1990 or the January 13, 2003 (taking in any month) format from user input, and any other date format I do not want to accept. I am struggling on how I would use the replace or find function to obtain these goals? Once I receive that format I want to print out the date in this format 7/19/22. If I have the dates in the right format I used the replace function to replace the space, and comma but how would I take that month and replace it with its numerical value? Sorry for all these questions I am just stuck and have been working on this for a while now.

> April 1, 1990
> November 2 1995
> 7/19/22
> January 13, 2003

```
userinput = input("Please enter date")

parsed_date = userinput.replace(" ", "/", 2)
new_parsed_date = parsed_date.replace(',',"")
print(new_parsed_date)
```

March/1/2019 
Here is my output when I parse the date. Is there also any easier way to do this task?

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the `strptime` method of the Python `datetime` object.

Basically you would write code that looks like this:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.strptime("January 13, 2003", "%B %d, %Y")
datetime.datetime(2003, 1, 13, 0, 0)
```

Documentation for `strptime`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime

Answer (score 1):

I can't really understand what you're going to do. You said that you only want to accept the certain dates formats from user input and ignore other dates formats.

```
April 1, 1990      # Accept
January 13, 2003   # Accept
November 2 1995    # Ignore (lack of comma)
7/19/22            # Ignore (use numerical value in month field)
```

May I just think that you would like to accept the format like `January 13, 2003` and print or save them in the format `01/13/2003`?

Then you should consider [`strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) and [`strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime) methods for `datetime` object.

```py
# get the date string from user input
date_input = input("Please Enter Date: ") 
input_format = "%B %d, %Y"
output_format = "%m/%d/%Y"

try:
    parsered_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_input, input_format)
                                     .strftime(output_format)
    print(parsered_date)
except ValueError:
    print("This is the incorrect date string format.")
```